# Right way to transfer a CSV file to a BI application?

Tags: http, ftp

We are doing a BI application, and our customers send us data files daily. We are doing data exchange using CSV files, because our customers are used to watch data with Excel, and they are not ready yet to use an API on their system (maybe in few years we will be able to use XML/JSON webservice, we hope).

Currently the data transfer is made with FTP (SFTP in fact). Our customers upload file automatically on an FTP server, and we have a CRON task that watches if a file has been sent.

But there are many disadvantages with that:

- We cannot know with reliability if the upload is done, or still in progress (we asked them to upload a file with a temporary name, and move it after, but many of them still don't do that)
- So, we can try to guess, and consider upload is done if enough time has passed. But FTP protocol doesn't allow to get server time, and time can be desynced. So we can upload an empty file and read it's date to know the time of the server. But we need write permission to do that...
- FTP protocol allow to pause upload...

Then, we are considering to transfer files by asking our customer to upload them directly on our application, using HTTPS. This is more reliable, but less convenient:

- Our customer cannot check the content of the file after upload
- We have to be careful with upload size and timeout on our server
- Files can be quite large (up to 300Mo), so it's better to zip them before upload (can reduce size to 10%).
- This is more work for us than just an FTP server (we need to create UI, upload progress, list files to download them back, ...)

There is other solutions? How usually BI applications share data? Is HTTPS a good solutions for us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found a solution which is a webdav server. We are using Nextcloud, it provides an online interface, and script access with webdav protocol.

It's more reliable than FTP, because the file appear only when upload is done.
And it's better than HTTP upload on our application. We don't have to handle file upload, create interfaces, ...